# Get entity have max association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 2 models like this :

```
User
    has_many :contacts


Contact
    belongs_to :user
```

How can I get the User who have the max number of contacts ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd [use a counter cache column on your User model:](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to)

```
# db/schema.rb
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "contacts_count"
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User
  has_many :contacts
end
# app/models/contact.rb
class Contact
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Then you could use ActiveRecord's [maximum calculation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/maximum) to easily pull up the user with the max number of contacts with a single query:

```
User.maximum(:contacts)
```